# backbone model save not working

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I tried to use Backbone.js model to sync data with the server. However the save method doesn't work. Any one can help me to find out why?

The following code works (not using Backbone model):

```
var newComment = {
    user: user,
    createdDate: date,
    content: text
  }

  //TODO send ajax post request to record the data

  $.ajax({
    url: "comment.php",
    context: document.body,
    data: newComment,
    type: 'POST'
  }).done(function(resp) {
    console.log("resp", resp);
  });
```

The code not working:

```
var Comment = Backbone.Model.extend({
     urlRoot: 'comment.php'
  });

var comment = new Comment();
comment.save({content: text, dsm_line_item_id: "49934380"}, {
    succcess: function(model, resp, opt) {
          console.log("successfully saved" + resp);
        },
    error: function(model, resp, opt) {
          console.log("error", resp);
        }
    })
```

Comment: What is the error message displayed in the console? Does it work when you add a leading slash to the url (`url: "/comment.php"`)?

Comment: no error messages. the success and error callbacks are not called. adding leading slash doesn't work either....

Comment: What about information regarding the AJAX call? See in the network tab in the console.

Comment: I will grab a screen shot on the network tab and attach it to the original question later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
succcess: function(model, resp, opt) {
```

**is this a typo**

Supposed to be  `success: function(model, resp, opt) {`

Answer (score 0):

This is a guess, but I think that it might be the answer. Backbone's `save` delegates to `Backbone.sync`, the function that Backbone uses to read or save models to the server.

Backbone uses POST, GET, DELETE and PUT; but some servers have problems with PUT and DELETE. Maybe your server has a problem with PUT and that's why your code isn't working.

You could try with `Backbone.emulateHTTP = true;`. That option allows you to work with legacy web servers that don't support Backbone's RESTful approach. The PUTs and DELETEs will be subsituted with POSTs during the sync.

Comment: Thanks. I tried and did not work. The request is POST and I believe I am using late version of PHP which should do with the situation.

Comment: Mmm. What a pity. My guess was that you were using POST in the example that worked and probably Backbone was using PUT in the one that wasn't working. I'll delete the answer as it was wrong. Good luck!

Comment: On second thoughts I think that I won't delete the answer. Somebody with a similar problem could find this and maybe the answer applies to his case and helps him.